# Windows Compact Embedded Not Automatically Deployed

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, deployment, windows-ce, .net-cf-3.5

I have a strange behavior with Visual Studio 2013 and .Net Compact Framework:

I can compile my WinCE program correctly, I can deploy it and start in debug mode by pressing F5. Everything is fine. But if I change my program and press F5 the application is compiled but not deployed, debugging starts with the old application.
(after than I can deploy the application and start it by hand, so I see it's compiled but not deployed)

If I start a new solution, add a new Visual C# project it all works correct. It worked in my working solution but not anymore. My working solution has a 'C# Class Library', 2 C# projects and 1 C++ project.

Hardware is a Toradex Ixora with Windows Embedded Compact 2013, VS 2013 Update 5.

Answer (score 1):

Ah, a little embarrassing:
Right click on solution -> expand 'Configuration Properties' -> click 'Configuration'

There the checkmarks are missing for 'Deploy'